# Flutter just_audio package throws null exception if I show more than 10 sounds in my ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, just-audio

I am trying to build a simple app that plays audio files in the asset folder.

I am using a Stream Builder to return a card for each sound to show pause and play icons. but strangely my app throws a null error when I add more than 10 sounds in the sound model.

**here is my sound model class :**

```
class CoughViewModel extends ChangeNotifier{

  final List<SoundModel> _soundsList = [
    SoundModel(soundIcon: 'assets/vectors/death_bed.svg', soundName: 'DEATH BED', soundPath: 'assets/sounds/cough_sounds/death_bed.mp3'),
  ];

  List<SoundModel> get soundsList => _soundsList;
}
```

**here is the code which I am using to display the sound cards :**

```
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: soundModel.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
          return SoundCard(soundTitle: soundModel[index].soundName,soundPath: soundModel[index].soundPath,cardPicture: soundModel[index].soundIcon,);
      }),
    ),
```

**here is my stream builder :**

```
return StreamBuilder<PlayerState>(
      stream: player.playerStateStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("STATEOFPLAYER : ${player.playerStateStream}");
        final playerState = snapshot.data;
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return _cardReturner(playerState!);
        }
        else{
          return const CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: MyColors.color3,
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

**here is my widget returner function :**

```
  Widget _cardReturner(PlayerState playerState) {
    final processingState = playerState.processingState;
    if (player.playing != true) {
      return soundCard(isPlaying: false);
    } else if (processingState != ProcessingState.completed) {
      return soundCard(isPlaying: true);
    } else {
      return soundCard(isPlaying: false);
    }
  }
```

for some strange reason my **player.playerStateStream's** playerState gets null when number of sounds in model increase to 11

If I manually set the ListView.builder's itemCount to 10 the app runs with no problem. but as soon as the number exceeds I get an exception

[image: MANUAL ITEM COUNT 9]

[image: SOUNDMODEL.LENGTH ITEM COUNT]

**furthermore here is my soundCard code**

```
class SoundCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? cardPicture;
  final String soundTitle;
  final String soundPath;

  const SoundCard({Key? key,this.cardPicture,required this.soundTitle,required this.soundPath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SoundCardState createState() => _SoundCardState();
}

class _SoundCardState extends State<SoundCard> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  final Icon playIcon = const Icon(
    Icons.play_arrow,
    color: MyColors.color3,
  );
  final Icon pauseIcon = const Icon(
    Icons.pause,
    color: MyColors.color3,
  );

  final String playString = 'TAP TO PLAY';
  final String pauseString = 'TAP TO PAUSE';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    player.setAsset(widget.soundPath);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.setContext(context);
    return StreamBuilder<PlayerState>(
      stream: player.playerStateStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("STATEOFPLAYER : ${player.playerStateStream}");
        final playerState = snapshot.data;
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return _cardReturner(playerState!);
        }
        else{
          return const CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: MyColors.color3,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _cardReturner(PlayerState playerState) {
    final processingState = playerState.processingState;
    if (player.playing != true) {
      return soundCard(isPlaying: false);
    } else if (processingState != ProcessingState.completed) {
      return soundCard(isPlaying: true);
    } else {
      return soundCard(isPlaying: false);
    }
  }

  Widget soundCard({required bool isPlaying}) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:25.w,right: 25.w,top: 10.h,bottom: 10.h),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: MyColors.color2,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.r))),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () async {
          if (isPlaying) {
            player.stop();
          } else {
            player.setAsset(widget.soundPath);
            player.play();
          }
        },
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              widget.cardPicture??'assets/vectors/sound_icon_cough.svg',
              height: 30.h,
            ),
            backgroundColor: MyColors.color1,
          ),
          title: Text(
            widget.soundTitle,
            style: MyTextStyles.bold15.copyWith(color: MyColors.color3),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            isPlaying ? pauseString : playString,
            style: MyTextStyles.medium15.copyWith(color: MyColors.color1),
          ),
          trailing: isPlaying ? pauseIcon : playIcon,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**STACKTRACE**

```
flutter: STATEOFPLAYER : Instance of 'BehaviorSubject<PlayerState>'

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building StreamBuilder<PlayerState>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<PlayerState, AsyncSnapshot<PlayerState>>#075ca):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<PlayerState> StreamBuilder:file:///Users/junaidtariq/Documents/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/the_hoax_flu/lib/global_widgets.dart:141:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.widget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3203:31)
#1      debugCheckHasMediaQuery.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:229:17)
#2      debugCheckHasMediaQuery (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:245:4)
#3      MediaQuery.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart:859:12)
#4      ScreenUtil.screenWidth (package:flutter_screenutil/screen_util.dart:69:51)
#5      ScreenUtil.scaleWidth (package:flutter_screenutil/screen_util.dart:88:28)
#6      ScreenUtil.setWidth (package:flutter_screenutil/screen_util.dart:101:41)
#7      SizeExtension.w (package:flutter_screenutil/size_extension.dart:5:32)
#8      _SoundCardState.soundCard (package:the_hoax_flu/global_widgets.dart:171:39)
#9      _SoundCardState._cardReturner (package:the_hoax_flu/global_widgets.dart:161:14)
#10     _SoundCardState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:the_hoax_flu/global_widgets.dart:147:18)
#11     StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:442:81)
#12     _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:124:48)
#13     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#15     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#17     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#18     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#19     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#20     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#21     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#22     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#26     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#27     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#28     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================
```

**I am on a deadline as I have to deliver this app to a client. any help would be highly appreciated thankyou**

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @passsy I've edited the question and added stack trace. Please review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access the `.w` extension when calling `25.w`. This only works when the context inside `ScreenUtil` is up to date, it doesn't work with an outdated context (from the last build).

The `build` callback of `StreamBuilder` updates independently of your Widgets `build` function.

The `StreamBuilder` build function is called way more often. Therefore, you have to call `ScreenUtil.setContext(context);` again to update the BuildContext.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.setContext(context);
    return StreamBuilder<PlayerState>(
      stream: player.playerStateStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        // Update context
        ScreenUtil.setContext(context);

        print("STATEOFPLAYER : ${player.playerStateStream}");
        final playerState = snapshot.data;
        if (snapshot.hasData){
          return _cardReturner(playerState!);
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: MyColors.color3,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```